# Derive data likelihood for conditional probability for autologistic model

Tags: autocorrelation, markov-random-field

The log conditional probability for the autologistic model is

$\log\Pr(y_i\mid \{y_j : j \neq i\}) = \alpha_iy_i + \sum_j^N\theta_{ij}y_iy_j - \log(1 + \exp(a_i + \sum_j^N\theta_{ij}y_j))$

From Cressie's [Statistics for Spatial Data](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1119114616), I follow how the conditional probability follows from the definition of *negpotentials*, and how that implies that the log likelihood have the form.

$\log \Pr(\mathbf{y}) = \sum_i^N\alpha_iy_i + \mathop{\sum\sum}_{1 \leq i < j \leq N} \theta_{ij}y_iy_j - \sum_{\mathbf{z} \in \zeta}\exp(\sum_i^N\alpha_iz_i + \mathop{\sum\sum}_{1 \leq i < j \leq N} \theta_{ij}z_iz_j)$

where $\zeta$ is the set of all configurations of the N sites.

For my own understanding, I've been trying to find a derivation of the full likelihood from the conditional probabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autologistic model has an intractable likelihood in the sense that it involves a normalizing constant that cannot be obtained in closed form (this is, you cannot derive the full likelihood and its evaluation is computationally expensive). There is a recent paper that describes this difficulty and proposes an approximation to the maximum likelihood estimator that does not require the evaluation of the likelihood function:

> Bee, M., Espa, G., & Giuliani, D. (2015). [Approximate maximum likelihood estimation of the autologistic model](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947314003119). *Computational Statistics & Data Analysis*, 84, 14-26.

Comment: Welcome to our site! We appreciate full citations for references (authors, date, journal etc) just in case links locations ever change - that should still allow future readers to find the article in the event of the link stopping working. Sadly we have a significant problem with link-rot in our older answers. I've filled this one in for you - the Google Scholar "Cite" button is useful for generating citations automatically.

Comment: @Silverfish Thank you. I agree with your changes and I will keep in mind your advice.

Comment: No problem - using "cite" on Google Scholar this took literally seconds.